# How to convert an Upper case string to lower case string in DWT, Tridion

Tags: tridion, dwt

How to convert an Upper case string to lower case string in DWT, Tridion?

I have a field in schema called ' title'.
 I got the value of title in DWT using "@@RenderComponentField(FieldPath+".title", 0)@@". 
I want to convert the returned value in to small letters.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a .Net TBB to get the value and add it to the package in the format you require, or create a custom Function Source that contains a function that is callable from the template to create your desired output. I'd say that a Function Source is probably the better of the two options. You can find an example, and sample code, at http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/dreamweaver_get_extension.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this in DWT by using either a TBB or a custom function (as Jeremy has explained).

But you might also want to consider doing the same in the CSS of your site.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-transform

```
p { text-transform: lowercase; }
```

Which approach is best depends on the reason for wanting the text to become lowercase. Given that you are using a title field in your example, I expect that the reason is closely related to styling requirements - in which case I'd take the CSS route.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following expression? (I can't test it right now) It includes JScript, which should work.

`@@"${RenderComponentField(FieldPath + ".title", 0)}".toLowerCase()@@`

Comment: Indeed, this is the answer! (So it turns some JS subset can be used within DWT)